# Moving "Category" to the "Content" in the Frontend Edit

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, editing

This is a hard question I know that. But i hope someone somehow have the answer for it.

When you login the fronted in Joomla, and press "edit article" and you can se the tabs which are "Content" "Public"  "Language" etc.

In "Public" there is the category textfield. i want to move that to the "Content" tab. is it possible somehow? I was thinking its maybe inside the article.xml file but im not sure.

Components --> Com_content --> Models --> Forms --> article.xml

But im not sure how to do it. Anyone can have a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an override of `com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php` in your template and move this row:

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('catid'); ?>
```

in the `<div class='tab-pane'>` that you want.
You can easily change the order of every field, just pay attention to keep this rows inside form and fieldset tags.

Avoid editing the xml file, or on next joomla updates you could lose custom edits.